# SceneKit: Transform texture to fill only part of a sphere

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm developing an application that uses SceneKit API and I faced the problem that I basically cannot apply a texture to a sphere object and keep texture's pre-defined size. I'm able to either scale the texture up to the object's surface (default SceneKit's behavior) or repeat it. But what I want to achieve is similar to the billiard ball:

[image]

Let's say I have a a .png image of a white circle with the number "13" at the center of it. I want to put it like the one on the picture. Generally, I want it to be scaled up to a fixed size, not the whole surface.

I use `material.diffuse.contents` property of `SCNGeometry` to set the texture and I found `contentsTransform` property in the documentation which can probably help me sort it out but I didn't find an explanation how to use it with the **sphere** object.

Is it something that is possible with pure SceneKit? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> You need a preliminarily modelled geometry (polygonal sphere in your case) and its **`UV Mapped texture`** that's made in 3D modelling software (Autodesk Maya for instance).

Watch [this short movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDXEvQdCEKk) to find out how to get UV-mapped texture.